# wp_insert_post() function returns error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have following php code that placed under my wordpress website.
I get return 0 with the following error message:

> Could not insert post into the database

My php code is:

```
include('/home/xxx/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php');
$my_wp_post = array();
$my_wp_post['post_title'] = 'it is title';
$my_wp_post['post_content'] = 'it is content';
$my_wp_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
$my_wp_post['post_author'] = 1;
$my_wp_post['ping_status'] = 1;
$my_wp_post['post_category'] = array('0');
#var_dump($my_wp_post);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_wp_post, true );
    if (is_wp_error($post_id)) 
    {
    $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo "- " . $error . "<br />";
        }
    }
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Where do you put this code? Like for me `wp-blog-header.php` has wrong path, I tested it with `wp_head();` and working fine.

Comment: it is under root_directory/my_folder

Comment: Try to place absolute path for test.

Comment: i updated as /home/xxx/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php but sitll getting same error

Comment: No, just add hardcoded URL example.com/wp-content/....

Comment: i updated code example. is it as u suggest?

Comment: Yes - just URL path.

Comment: but still it doesn't work !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133246/discussion-between-mattkrupnik-and-mahsum-akbas).

Answer (score 1):

i found problem. because my php file encoding is ANSI it cause some non-ascii character problems. i changed it into UTF-8 and problem is solved. 
Thanks for your support